# How do I specify Custom Arguments with Cake Builder? (DotNetCore)

Tags: c#, msbuild, cakebuild

I have a Cake automated build script used to build a solution in various configurations. I am trying to write a Web Deploy task that will package up a solution, and send it to the server. To make the process more repeatable and less flimsy, I've opted to store the package in C:/projectName.

Using cake and DotNetCore, how can I specify a Web Deploy package (zip) output folder? Here is what I have so far:

```
Task("DeployRelease")
    .Does(() =>
    {
        foreach(var webConfig in config.projConfigs){
            Debug($"Publishing website: {webConfig.WebsiteServer}");

            DotNetCoreMSBuild(csprojPath, new DotNetCoreMSBuildSettings()
                .WithProperty("DeployOnBuild","true")
                .SetConfiguration(config.Configuration)
                .ArgumentCustomization(args=>args.Append($"/OutputPath={webConfig.BuildPath}"));


            var deploySettings = new DeploySettings()
            {
                SourcePath = webConfig.BuildPath,
                SiteName = webConfig.WebsiteName,
                ComputerName = webConfig.WebsiteServer,
                Username = webConfig.DeployUser,
                Password = webConfig.DeployToken
            };
            DeployWebsite(deploySettings);

            Debug($"Completed Web Deploy on: {webConfig.WebsiteServer}");
        }
    });
```

The above code should work (at least as I interpreted the docs) but I get the following error:

> C:/Development/{project}/build.{project}.cake(355,40): error CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'ProcessArgumentBuilder' because it is not a delegate type

Docs: https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core.Tooling/ToolSettings/50AAB3A8
    https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.DotNetCore.MSBuild/DotNetCoreMSBuildBuilder/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArgumentCustomization is a property on all tool settings, so correct syntax would be:

```
new DotNetCoreMSBuildSettings {
    ArgumentCustomization = args=>args.Append($"/OutputPath={webConfig.BuildPath}")

}.WithProperty("DeployOnBuild","true")
 .SetConfiguration(config.Configuration);
```

Comment: Code did not compile (not sure if I'm on an outdated C# version) and `var buildSettings = new DotNetCoreMSBuildSettings() {
                    ArgumentCustomization = args=>{
                        args.Append($"/OutputPath={webConfig.BuildPath}");
                        return args;
                        }
                };` threw **.NET Core CLI: Process returned an error (exit code 1). MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.**

Comment: By bad, I had an ; too much, shouldn't be any after ArgumentCustomization. I've updated answer.